# Javascript Not returining text in function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

Im relatively new to expressjs, having a hard time dealing with functions

I want to use this function to call between results:

Working Result:

```
function flag1(newflag){
    console.log('This is'+newflag+' Got it?')
}

flag1('My_Flag')

// Result: This is My Flag Got it?
```

For example:

> res.send('Blah Blah Blah '+flag2('My_Flag')+' Blah Blah Blah')

Expected Result:

> Blah Blah Blah My_Flag Blah Blah Blah

This Question is based on Expressjs, but others might be able to help too

Comment: You'll need a `return` statement so that `flag2()`, when called, produces a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second example `'This is '+newflag+' Got it?'` creates a string.

That is **all** it does.

It doesn't pass it to another function (like `console.log` or `res.send`).

It doesn't assign it to a variable.

It doesn't assign it to a property of an object.

It doesn't [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) it so it can be used on the left hand side of `flag2('My_Flag')` (not that you have anything on the left hand side of that function call … although you do in the later example: `res.send('Blah Blah Blah '+flag2('My_Flag')+' Blah Blah Blah')`).

Since you don't do anything, the string is thrown away immediately after it is created (unless the compiler optimises the string creation away entirely).

---

If you want to do something with the string, then you have to write code which does that.

Comment: @HOH_HOH — Reread this answer. I specifically mentioned returning in it.

Comment: Yoooo it was that easy, im confused how can i forget something so basic, using Js after 1 year...

Answer (score 0):

This Worked:

```
function flag1(newflag){
   return (newflag);      
}

res.send('Blah Blah Blah '+flag2('My_Flag')+' Blah Blah Blah')
```

Its so simple, forgot return